# How do I run an XSLT file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am writing an XSLT file to translate an XML document into an XHTML document. I've used both Visual Studio and [XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en) to preview the results of my XSLT file, but now I want to actually write out a real XHTML file so I can see how it looks in other browsers.

Neither Visual Studio or XML NotePad have an obvious way to save the preview. Am I missing something. Obviously the file is getting created because something is being previewed, but I need to know where that file is being created or better yet choose its location.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Visual Studio, add the XML file to a project.  Open the XML file.  When the file is open and its window is active, you should see, in the Properties window, that you can specify an output filename and a stylesheet.  Also, you should see that the menu bar now contains an "XML" item.

If you pick "Show XSLT output" from the "XML" menu, VS will apply the specified transform to the XML file, write its output to the file you specified, and then open that file.  If the file has an `.xml` extension, it'll open it in a text editor window; if it has an `.htm` extension, it'll open it in a browser window.

It's a little bit clunky (it seems to me that a menu that appears and vanishes instead of being enabled/disabled is kind of hinky), but it works well enough, and it's in the tool you're already using.

Comment: hmm i see get the menu point "Show XSLT output". Running VS2012. Am I missing something?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 you can follow the steps in this answer but choose the "Start XSLT Without Debugging" option in the XML menu.

Answer (score 39):

You have two options:

1. Let the browser do it. Pass the XML with a reference to the XSLT and the browser (IE 6 or lower might have problems) will render it as (X)HTML:

   `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.example.com/my-xslt.xsl" ?>`
2. Do it server-side. Most languages have methods for accepting XSLT and XML data, then outputting (X)HTML. Here are some options:

   - [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28VS.85%29.aspx)
   - [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net)
   - [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/)

[image]

Comment: Note that option 1 may not be applicable if your XSLT includes C# code snippets.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind going to the command line and XSLT 1.0 is what you want: [msxsl.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714)

Comment: For windows, I would rather recommend NXSLT 3.0 for 1.0, and of course Saxon for 2.0.

Comment: What's the reason that NXSLT is better? (Just interested.)

Comment: +1 for being the solution I ended up using at the time, but Roberts solution would have been better.

Comment: Just a note for some, that the link for msxsl.exe is dead... (its 6 years old anyway) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2FB55371-C94E-4373-B0E9-DB4816552E41

Answer (score 5):

For a one-off task where you do not want to go thru the pain of an install, you could probably use https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html. I'l disclaim that I have not used this site much.

Answer (score 4):

There are many third-party software. One of them is "Oxygen XML Editor".
In this software, simply:

1. Open your .xml
2. Open your .xslt
3. Click "run" in the toolbar for see results( output will be in the right panel).
4. If you want to save result, R-click on result in right panel and choose "save ..."
5. If you have problem, may be you need change processing in toolbar: "Xalan,Saxon,Saxon-HE,saxon-PE,..."

Comment: It’s quite expensive (starting “from $99”), so there might be a better answer that helps more people.

Comment: @dakab You are right! But this is one of the answers and maybe help someone!

Comment: There are some good articles in the field of C#, such as: [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130329123237/http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=63) `article`