# Concat with Xsl

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Let me start off by saying I am a complete noob to Xsl. I am trying to accomplish what I feel is pretty simple, but I am having a hard time understanding the syntax.

I have a variable that gets a location name (ex. Chicago or Orland)

Then I have a variable that gets a phone number without an area code.

So what I am trying to do is a If statement that Concat("Area Code" with the "Phone Number") based off if location is Chicago (773), or Orland (708).

Variables:

```
xsl:variable name="haswph"       select="string-length(workphone) &gt; 0"
xsl:variable name="hasonum"      select="string-length(officenumber) &gt; 0"
```

Output:

```
  <xsl:if test="$haswph">
    <li id="PhoneField">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/workphone" />
    </li>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$hasonum">
    <li id="OfficeField">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/officenumber" />
    </li>
  </xsl:if>
```

Any suggestions, or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Brandon

```
<preferredname>Nigro, Brandon L.</preferredname> 
<yomidisplayname></yomidisplayname>
<department>Information Technology</department> 
<workphone>555-5555</workphone>
<officenumber>John Academic Center</officenumber>
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a sample of the input XML and desired output.  Also, where is "location" in the input?  You haven't shown what determines if the office is Chicago or Orlando

Comment: Its coming from AD, this xsl is a chunk from a SharePoint webpart.

Comment: Fine, but we still need to see a sample of input and output, as well as where in the XML "location" comes from.

Comment: Excuse my incompetence. I believe the input is already set from AD, right when the Web Part loads. In that top part of code WorkPhone is set with my Number already and same with officenumber. I have added the XML Code in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, solution passes through simply adding this template to your current xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="workphone">
    <xsl:if test="$office='Chicago'">(773) </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$office='Orland'">(708) </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

replacing this "$office" variable by the one you referred in your original post.

**EDIT**: Here you have a a complete tranformation where the previous template is applied to a sample input XML (BTW: Try following Jim Garrison suggestion. Post complete input/output XML instead of parts of them in future posts and you'll get the exact response at the first try).

Input:

```
    <Office code="Chicago">
        <Employee id="1">
            <hithighlightedproperties>
                <preferredname>Nigro, Brandon L.</preferredname>
                <yomidisplayname></yomidisplayname>
                <department>Information Technology</department>
                <workphone>555-5555</workphone>
                <officenumber>John Academic Center</officenumber>
            </hithighlightedproperties>
        </Employee>
    </Office>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="office" select="Office/@code"/>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="Office">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Employee"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <xsl:variable name="haswph" select="string-length(hithighlightedproperties/workphone) &gt; 0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="hasonum" select="string-length(hithighlightedproperties/officenumber)&gt; 0"/>
        <p>Employee <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> Properties</p>
        <ul>
            <li id="Name"><xsl:value-of select="hithighlightedproperties/preferredname"/></li>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(hithighlightedproperties/yomidisplayname)">
                <li id="DisplayNameField">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/yomidisplayname"/>
                </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <li id="DepartmentField"><xsl:value-of select="hithighlightedproperties/department"/></li>
            <xsl:if test="$haswph">
                <li id="PhoneField">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/workphone"/>
                </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hasonum">
                <li id="OfficeField">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/officenumber"/>
                </li>
            </xsl:if>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="workphone">
        <xsl:if test="$office='Chicago'">(773) </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$office='Orland'">(708) </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Employee 1 Properties</p>
        <ul>
            <li id="NameField">Nigro, Brandon L.</li>
            <li id="DepartmentField">Information Technology</li>
            <li id="PhoneField">(773) 555-5555</li>
            <li id="OfficeField">John Academic Center</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I discourage you from using this "variable + if" approach, and try using the clean xsl pushy style (This achieves exactly the same result):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="Office">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Employee"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <p>Employee <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> Properties</p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/preferredname" mode="li">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'NameField'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/yomidisplayname" mode="li">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'DisplayNameField'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/department" mode="li">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'DepartmentField'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/workphone" mode="li">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'PhoneField'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/officenumber" mode="li">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'OfficeField'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="workphone">
        <xsl:variable name="office" select="../../../@code"/>
        <xsl:if test="$office='Chicago'">(773) </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$office='Orland'">(708) </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="*[string-length(.)&gt;0]" mode="li">
        <xsl:param name="id" select="local-name()"/>
        <li id="{$id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It did not work. :( After I added that to my code, there were no changes.

Should the template match park equal workphone or should it equal the id of workphone in this case OfficeField (stated in the first post).

Also should I been placing that below or above where the workphone is outputted?

Comment: Ok, sorry. Maybe I gave you too less information. Now I'll edit the post giving you all the required details

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I didn't realize that xsl has HTML with it. So say I wanted to test the functionality, is it as simple as copying this into notepad, setting the variables, and opening in the browser?

Comment: Yes, it should work like that. You can have a look at this other answer which explains how to set it up: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1590114/921383