# XSLT problems with an XML: <xsl:value> returns empty string

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having some issues with my code, but I don't know what's wrong.
It is supposed to take elements from the XML file and show them as items in a table. The table shows up just fine but the problem is that there are no elements.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bibliography>
  <book>
    <title>
      Hello World
    </title>
    <author>
      Ross Andrews
    </author>
    <article>
      Article1
    </article>
    <bookreport>
      Book Report1
    </bookreport>
    <presentation>
      Presentation1
    </presentation>
    <weblink>
      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590085/how-do-i-run-an-xslt-file
    </weblink>
    <softwarepackage>
      Word
    </softwarepackage>
  </book>
</bibliography>
```

And here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="books.xml">
<xsl:template match ="\">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>
                Bibliography Entries
            </h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th style="text-align:left">
                        Title
                    </th>                       
                    <th style="text-align:left">
                        Author
                    </th>                       
                    <th style="text-align:left">
                        Article
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">
                        Book Report
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">
                        Presentation
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">
                        Web Link
                    </th>                       
                    <th style="text-align:left">
                        Software package
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
                        </td>                       
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="article"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="bookreport"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="presentation"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="weblink"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="softwarepackage"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Change your `xsl:for-each` to `<xsl:for-each select="bibliography/book">`. Without any xpath in the select attribute you should actually get an error. By specifying the xpath you are iterating on the selected nodes and creating `<tr>` elements.

Comment: I've made the change but it didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive name. For instance, you could title it "Selecting nothing in xsl:for-each selects nothing".

Comment: @torazaburo: Done ;-) Not exactly your wording, but I think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems with your XSLT. The first is how you have declared the `xsl` namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="books.xml">
```

The `xsl` namespace prefix needs to be defined with a specific namespace URI so that the XSLT processor can recognise the XSLT elements to process

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

If you want XML to be transformed by XSLT, you should be adding the following processing instruction to your XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl" href="books.xsl" ?>
```

The next issue is you have a template matching `\`, but it should be `/` to match the document element

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

And finally, you have an `xsl:for-each` which selects nothing. It should select `bibliography/book`

```
<xsl:for-each select="bibliography/book">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Bibliography Entries</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>                       
                    <th style="text-align:left">Author</th>                       
                    <th style="text-align:left">Article</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Book Report</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Presentation</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Web Link</th>                       
                    <th style="text-align:left">Software package</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="bibliography/book">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
                        </td>                       
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="article"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="bookreport"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="presentation"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="weblink"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="softwarepackage"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl" href="books.xsl" ?>
<bibliography>
<book>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <author>Ross Andrews</author>
    <article>Article1</article>
    <bookreport>Book Report1</bookreport>
    <presentation>Presentation1</presentation>
    <weblink>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590085/how-do-i-run-an-xslt-file</weblink>
    <softwarepackage>Word</softwarepackage>
</book>
</bibliography>
```

See this in action at http://xsltransform.net/94rmq7f/1

Comment: I have done as you asked but I still don't see any change.

Comment: Is the XML in your question accurate, or is your actual XML different? In particular does your XML have a namespace declaration? (i.e does it have `xmlns=".."` in it?

Comment: The XML code I have given is basically a copy-paste of what I had in my XML file.

Comment: Can you show what you currently have at http://xsltransform.net/ (just paste in your XML and XSLT there, and click "Save")?

Comment: Well, that appears to work, which is good! How are you actually performing the transformation? Simply by viewing the XML in the browser?

Comment: I was opening the xslt file in my browser. Should I have been opening the XML one instead?

Comment: I had a weird bug with my Internet Explorer and I needed to restart my computer. After that it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!