# Is there a way for XSLT to keep the xml declaration?

Tags: .net, xml, excel, xslt

I have an XSLT that transforms XML to XLSX. The Workbook tags are properly generated. However the problem is, Excel can't open the file if it has no `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on first line of .xlsx.

Tried manually adding xml declaration to xlsx via Notepad, Excel then can open the Workbook.

I tried adding `omit-xml-declaration="no"` to `xslt:output` tag, problem is, the browser seems to ignore it, there's no xml decleration generated on top of XLSX XML file.

If browsers will just ignore the omit-xml-declaration attribute, I'll just convert the XML to XLSX via .NET's XSLT library. What's the up-to-date XSLT library for .NET?

**UPDATE**

This is the XML generated by SQL Server's XML functionality:

*Data.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="data.xsl"?>
<rows>
  <row>
    <AccountId>G</AccountId>
    <AccountName>Great</AccountName>
    <AcocuntStatus>Active</AcocuntStatus>
  </row>
  <row>
    <AccountId>N</AccountId>
    <AccountName>Nice</AccountName>
    <AcocuntStatus>Very Active</AcocuntStatus>
  </row>
</rows>
```

This is the XSLT that transforms the XML to Excel file.

*Data.xsl*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" > 

 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Workbook>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*">
  <Worksheet>
  <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
    <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
      <Row>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
          </Data></Cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Row>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <Row>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Row>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Data></Cell>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yeah, probably browser only has displayable output in mind when doing xslt transform, have you tried different browser though?

Comment: @StefanHegny Yes I tried all browsers, I checked the transformed XML via Inspect Element, all the excel tags are generated, the XML declaration is missing even with omit-xml-`declaration="no"`

Comment: @GreenLantern I don't understand your process: how do you use a browser to generate a transformed file?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I put this attribute to XML data's `<?xml-stylesheet` tag: `href="xsltUrlHere.xsl"`. I've yet to figure out how the browser can be forced to download the XLSX file. As of now, I can see the browser is capable of transforming XML to XML (the Excel file). I updated my question and included the XML file and the XSLT file.

Comment: I am afraid I still don't get it. If I open *data.xml* in a browser, I see this: http://imgur.com/aUOARhH If I view page source, I see the original XML. I can see the transformed XML if I do "Inspect Element" (in some browsers)  - but I cannot save this to a file.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes cannot preview it, and can only see the transformed XML if you do Inspect Element, regarding cannot save to a file, that's what I've yet to figure out.

Comment: So what's the point of this exercise? If you want to eventually view this in Excel, look for another tool to do the transformation. I am not a Windows user, but I believe Notepad can do this with a plugin? -- See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590085/how-do-i-run-an-xslt-file

Comment: @michael.hor257k The customer of web app want to either view the data as HTML or download it as Excel. I just want to reuse the same XML used by HTML-transforming XSLT on Excel converter.  I'm still in research stage, in fact I'm leaning now to do the transformation to Excel on server-side, looks like even I can nudge the browser to include xml declaration on first line, I still need to find out if the browser can make the Excel file transformed by XML+XSLT combo be downloadable

Comment: "*The customer want to either view it as HTML or download it as Excel.*"  Perhaps you should post a question about that. IMHO, if you serve them the XML with the current stylesheet into a browser, they won't be able to do either.